# Problem in Dungeon & Dragon game with python

Tags: python, while-loop

i just wrote this dungeon and dragon mini game, It's not completed yet , i didn't write the dragon function or the function to show an error when the user hits the wall. I just want to move the player " X " how many times i want , but i can't.
this is the code :

```
import random
import os

def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

dungeon = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),
        (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
        (2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),
        (3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),
        (4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)
        ]

def first_random_position():
    return(random.choice(dungeon))

def make_dungeon(player_position):
    print(" _ _ _ _ _")
    for cell in dungeon:
        y = cell[1]
        if y < 4:
            if cell == player_position:
                print("|X", end = "")
            else:
                print("|_", end = "")
        elif cell == player_position:
            print("|X|")
        else:
            print("|_|")

def move_player(position,m_input):
    x,y = position
    if m_input.upper() == "UP":
        x -= 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "LEFT":
        y -= 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "RIGHT":
        y += 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "DOWN":
        x += 1
    position = x,y
    return(x,y)

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Dungeon!")
    input("Press 'Enter' on your keyboard to start the game!")
    first_pos = first_random_position()
    make_dungeon(first_pos)
    print("You are currently in room {}".format(first_pos))
    print("Enter LEFT , RIGHT , UP and DOWN to move the 'X'")
    print("Enter 'QUIT' to quit")
    main_input = input("\n")
    location = move_player(first_pos,main_input)
    clear_screen()
    make_dungeon(location)

main()
```

as you can see, i just can move the X one time , but i want to be able to move it as many times as i want and i don't know how , i should write a while loop i guess? i tried but i failed and I really need your help . thanks

Comment: Read about loops here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know how loops work , i used them before , but in this case i dont know what i should do , writing a while loop only helps to take input again and again , but it doesnt solve my problem . i want to move the player but i have problem with the location , i cant update the location each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the lines:

```
main_input = input("\n")
location = move_player(first_pos,main_input)
clear_screen()
make_dungeon(location)
```

It asks for the user input only once as Patrick Artner commented you need to use [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) within your script.
If you surround that script with `while True:` it should let you continue to move:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Dungeon!")
    input("Press 'Enter' on your keyboard to start the game!")
    location = first_random_position()
    make_dungeon(location)
    print("You are currently in room {}".format(location))
    while True:
        print("Enter LEFT , RIGHT , UP and DOWN to move the 'X'")
        print("Enter 'QUIT' to quit")
        main_input = input("\n")
        location = move_player(location,main_input)
        clear_screen()
        make_dungeon(location)
```

You should use `location` rather than `first_pos` because it updates with the previous movement.

---

Although this is unrelated to the question I feel these changes will help your code for the future. Firstly, I would recommend adding `elif m_input.upper() == "QUIT": exit()` as a temporary way to exit your game. Secondly, rather than writing out the dungeon variable use list comprehension to create it `dungeon = [(x,y) for x in range(5) for y in range(5)]`.

---

**The Full Updated Code**

```
import random
import os

def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

dimensions = (6,6)
dungeon = [(x,y) for x in range(dimensions[0]) for y in range(dimensions[1])]

def first_random_position():
    return(random.choice(dungeon))

def make_dungeon(player_position):
    print(" _"*dimensions[1])
    for cell in dungeon:
        y = cell[1]
        if y < dimensions[1]-1:
            if cell == player_position:
                print("|X", end = "")
            else:
                print("|_", end = "")
        elif cell == player_position:
            print("|X|")
        else:
            print("|_|")

def move_player(position,m_input):
    x,y = position
    if m_input.upper() == "UP":
        x -= 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "LEFT":
        y -= 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "RIGHT":
        y += 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "DOWN":
        x += 1
    elif m_input.upper() == "QUIT":
        exit()
    position = x,y
    return(x,y)

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Dungeon!")
    input("Press 'Enter' on your keyboard to start the game!")
    location = first_random_position()
    make_dungeon(location)
    print("You are currently in room {}".format(location))
    while True:
        print("Enter LEFT , RIGHT , UP and DOWN to move the 'X'")
        print("Enter 'QUIT' to quit")
        main_input = input("\n")
        location = move_player(location,main_input)
        clear_screen()
        make_dungeon(location)
main()
```

Hope this helped.

---

Here is a simple explanation of the table for future reference:

[image: Simple Explanation]

Comment: Thanks for your response , but it only lets me to take input from user again again , i tried it before , my problem is with the location , it doesn't get updated each time. is it possible to write a function to return the location of X ? and thanks for your recommendation, i added that elif statement. edit : Thanks , i just saw you updated your answer , and it really helped me